# Unable to run IdentityServer3 in IIS

Tags: identityserver3

I have downloaded the code for IdentityServer from [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3). When running the IdentityServer3\Host.Web solution in IIS Express, I am able to authenticate from a console client using the TokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync method.

However, as soon as I switch IdentityServer3\Host.Web to run directly under IIS, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized 
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
Most likely causes:
- The username supplied to IIS is invalid.
- The password supplied to IIS was not typed correctly.
- Incorrect credentials were cached by the browser.
- IIS could not verify the identity of the username and password provided.
- The resource is configured for Anonymous authentication, but the configured anonymous account either has an invalid password or was disabled.
- The server is configured to deny login privileges to the authenticating user or the group in which the user is a member.
- Invalid Kerberos configuration may be the cause if all of the following are true:
    - Integrated authentication was used.
    - the application pool identity is a custom account.
    the server is a member of a domain.
```

What do I have to configure differently to get IdentityServer3 to work under IIS?

Comment: Is anonymous authentication allowed.

Comment: @BrockAllen - anonymous authentication is enabled, but it turns out that Basic Authentication was also enabled. By disabling Basic Authentication, IIS ignores the authentication headers and identityserver works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

It looks like a solution to this is to change the authentication type to PostValues:

```
var client = new TokenClient(
            authenticationUrl,
            "carbon",
            "21B5F798-BE55-42BC-8AA8-0025B903DC3B",
            AuthenticationStyle.PostValues);

var token = await client.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("bob", "secret", "api1");
```

Note that you must set the AuthenticationStyle in the constructor. Setting it after construction is problematic because the authentication headers are conditionally created in the constructor.

**Solution 2:**

Disable "Basic Authentication" in IIS Settings.

Comment: thank you..  it worked "Disable "Basic Authentication" in IIS Settings."
@rqdq